# How to install eventFilter on dynamically created QWidget?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, events, qwidget

i have just one QMainWindow with mainwindow.ui where i have tables, buttons etc...
From one button i want to dynamically create widget and set an evenFilter on it.

```
QWidget dialog = new QWidget();
dialog->installEventFilter(this);
```

When i compile program it says that     `QObject::installEventFilter(): Cannot filter events for objects in a different thread.`

How can i add this widget to thread with other Qobjects or what is best solution to this problem?

Comment: Does QWidget belong to a specific QThread (non-main)?

Comment: QWidget wasnt set for another thread by me. It was just created in mainwindow.cpp, not with designer in ui as other objects ui->tableView ..etc

Comment: Do you have other QObjects in different threads? All widgets should be in the main thread, you may use QObject::moveToThread to set thread of the particular QObject (main thread may be received by QApplication::instance()->thread()), but it is better to create all your widgets in the ui thread directly.

Comment: What the `this` pointer points to?

Comment: @nikitoz dialog = new QWidget();dialog->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread()); doesnt help :/

Comment: @vahancho this? im not sure, probadly mainwindow..everything is default

Comment: Then this is not in the UI thread. Post a definition of that class.

Comment: It is an error to ever create or move a QWidget to any thread other than the gui thread. It's an oversight in Qt's design that it doesn't make `moveToThread` at least `protected` in QWidget. If you're on a Mac, this has nothing to do with threads, but with the fact that you're running a debug build without using the debug version of the framework. This is easy to remedy by checking `Projects->Build&Run->Run->"Use debug version of frameworks"`.

Comment: @nikitoz MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, Database *db) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

Comment: #include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
}

Comment: asi you can see, im just creating original widget which i want to create in mainWindow class when i click on some button

Answer (score 0):

You should not create gui widgets from non gui threads.

Create subclass of QWidget and install there eventFilter, put inside signals to return result back.

And than send signal from your thread to main thread slot to create this `QWidget dialog = new MyWidget()` and use as you want.

Comment: Can you give me some blog about this? i dont understand why so simple thing is complicated

Comment: I don't know blog with answer. But remember that you can not access widgets, objects from another thread directly. The only way is to use signal slots.